# Find $f(x)$ given that $xf(x)+f(-x)=x$

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

$$xf(x)+f(-x)=x$$
$$f(x)= ?$$

I saw this question in a group and couldn't find a way out of it. I've tried various things one of which is down below but these don't seem to work out.

$$xf(x) + f(-x) = x$$
$$xf(-x)-f(x) = x$$
$$xf(x)+f(-x) = xf(-x) -f(x)$$
$$f(x)+f(-x)=x\left(f(-x)-f(x)\right)$$

I actually did proceed from here but it really was not useful at all. I even tried taking derivatives etc. but none of them worked.

I searched this functional equation question on Web but didn't find anything related to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Substituting 0 for x would be a good start. Did you try that?

Comment: @Trebor Yes, did that. Here are some values I have if I am not mistaken: $f(0) = f(1) = 0, f(2) = \frac{5}{2}, f(-1) = 1, f(-2) = -3.$

Comment: Actually, you have done everything needed: You wrote two equations of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$. Since there are two equations and two unknowns (remember currently we are solving for $f$, so the unknowns are $f(\pm x)$), you can solve the equations and obtain the unknowns.

Comment: It's worth stressing again: we want to express $f(x)$ in terms of $x$ (that's what 'solving for $f$' means, after all). So $x$ is a known number, and $f(x)$ is unknown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $x$ you have two equations:
$$\begin{cases} x f(x) + f(-x) = x \\
f(x) - x f(-x) = -x
\end{cases}$$
where the second equation is obtained by plugging $-x$ in the place of $x$.

This gives you a linear system with two equations and two unknowns $f(x), f(-x)$. The solution is
$$f(x)= \frac{x^2-x}{x^2+1}$$
Now, you can easily check that such a solution is well defined for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and satisfies the functional equation.

Answer (score 4):

$$ xf(x)+f(-x)=x~~~~(1)$$
Change $x\to -x$ to get
$$-xf(-x)+f(x)=-x~~~~(2)$$
Let $f(x)=A, f(-x)=B$,
then (1) and (2) become
$$xA+B=x ~ \& ~-xB+A=-x$$
Solve these two as linear simultaneous equations in $A$ and $B$, to get
$$B=\frac{x^2+x}{1+x^2}=f(-x)$$
and
$$A=\frac{x^2-x}{1+x^2}=f(x)$$